# How can I set the text of this ASPX control using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, input, textbox

I have the following `input` control in an `ASPX` page:

```
<input tabindex="0" class="_f_ql _f_rl textbox allowTextSelection placeholderText" role="textbox" aria-labelledby="MailCompose.SubjectWellLabel" autoid="_f_B2"></input>
```

I am only able to inject JavaScript into this page, and check if an `input` element with the above class is present, and **I would like to change the value of the text that is inside of this `textbox`**. Is there any way to do this with JavaScript?

So far, I can get the correct element using the following code, but setting the value on it does not work to set the `textbox`'s text to `Testing...`:

```
var subjectElements = getNodeElementsContainingID(document.body, "_f_ql _f_rl textbox allowTextSelection placeholderText");
if (subjectElements.length > 0) {
    subjectElements[0].value = "Testing...";
}
```

I don't want to inject jQuery as its overkill, but seeing as how I have the element I need, what can I do to it to set the text value on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementsByClassName('_f_ql _f_rl')[0].value = 'Testing...';
```

Comment: Ah, damn it, the class threw me off, well done man! Saved me so much time. It wasn't the ID, I don't even know why I read it as an ID!